# outputting smarty display function return to pdf using tcpdf

Tags: php, smarty, tcpdf

hi i am using smarty to print a calendar..
this calendar is displayed using the line

```
$html= $obj_smarty->fetch(FULLCAL_DIR.'/views/cal.html');
```

echoing $html in php gives me the calendar correctly. but i want to print this output to a pdf using tcpdf

i have used the following lines:

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('cal.pdf', 'I');
```

but it is not giving me the output.. only static data is displayed in the pdf. Please help

**UPDATE**
my pdf generation code is as follows:
$this->load->library('tcpdf');

```
     $pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    //$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Annual Planner');
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH,"Annual Planner","", array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
    //$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $html = "";
    require_once (APPPATH.'calendar/cal_include/default.inc.php');

    $html.= $obj_smarty->fetch(FULLCAL_DIR.'/views/cal.html');
    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

    $pdf->Output('cal.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with 'static data'.
We also use Smarty to build up templates with dynamic content which is then pushed to the writeHTML-function:

```
//CONTENT           
$sContent = $this->_oPDF->parseTemplate ($sTemplate,$aData);

//WRITE
$this->_oPDF->writeHTML($sContent, true, false, false, false, '');
```

The main process in parseTemplate()-method is (besides assigning language, clear compiled tpl,and so on):

```
//assigning dynamic data
$oTemplate->assign($aData);
//fetch template
$sContent = $oTemplate->fetch($sTemplate);
//return
return $sContent;
```

Hope this helps...